# How do you add a Web Reference to an SDK Style net48 Project?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to add a "Web Reference" to SDK style projects? I'm targeting net48 so would have thought there'd be support to add them but don't see an option for it. If I create a project using non SDK style then I do get the tooling.

I need to write a console app to help our testers that will allow them to get a dump of Report names on our internal Power BI Services (SSRS) server which only has an old school Web Service to code against. I know I can't use .NET Core and above, but would at least like to go with SDK projects if possible.

Comment: Hello Stephen, have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem. You can import a web reference in a non-sdk-project to generate the code. And then import the code to your sdk-project. That is only a workround. Maybe you found a better solution?